# In ARM assembly, BL instruction rightly links me back to initial routine but the address shown is always incorrect

Tags: assembly, arm, branch, subroutine, keil

Running this code after initializing on Keil for TM4C1233H6PM in THUMB mode:

`1) loop1
 2)    BL  loop2
 3)    MOV R3, #3
 4) loop2
 5)    PUSH {LR}
 6)    POP  {PC}`

Line (2) takes me to loop2 and stores 0x00000381 to the LR but after popping out the stack into the PC in line (6), the PC has 0x00000380 stored in it which is correctly the address of line (3).

Why does the PC take 0x00000380 when actually 0x00000381 was pushed in stack and popped out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ARM Cortex-M processors can execute either Thumb2 code or original ARM code, where all instructions are 32 bits. So, when returning from a subroutine the processor needs to know what kind of code it is returning to. If the LSB of the return address is set to 1 then the processor knows it is returning to Thumb2 code.

Note that actual instructions must be half-word aligned, so the true branch target address must have an LSB of 0. After checking the LSB to see what kind of code to execute, the processor forces the LSB to 0 before actually fetching the instruction.